# Easy-Post-Type is visible in search, but 404 when clicked

Tags: custom-post-types

- I've installed [Easy Post Types](http://www.wpeasyposttypes.com/documentation/theming#custom-post-templates)
- created a custom post type: Attractions
- created an Attraction: (joes-cafe)
- created a category set: attraction-type (cafe)
- copied single.php to single-attractions.php
- added the category: cafe to wp-navigation-menu

But when I visit the menu item, I get a 404,
when i search for the cafe by name, i see an excerpt, but clicking its title gives me a 404!

Any Clues? What am i doing wrong?

I am using a Thematic child theme, and i duplicated single-attractions.php as single-attraction.php just in case, because i found the distinction confusing...

Thanks, Tim

Comment: My apologies, people - everything seems to be working now, though I have no idea what I changed!

Comment: The rewrite rules need to be flushed when you add a custom post type, this can be done by visiting the permalinks admin page.

Comment: @Milo: Can you copy that comment in an answer? Then we can vote on it and get this question off the "unanswered" list.

Comment: You can click the checkbox next to Milo's answer to mark it as the one that helped you. I would upvote it, but I spent all my votes for the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite rules need to be flushed when you add a custom post type, this can be done by visiting the permalinks admin page.